# Rotation using Transformation Matrix

Tags: c++, qt, matrix, rotation, transformation

Can someone please explain to me what does this function do :

```
void QMatrix4x4::rotate (   const QQuaternion &     quaternion  )
```

In the documentation, it's written that it multiples ***this matrix*** by another that rotates coordinates according to a specified quaternion.
The question is which matrix is " this matrix" ? does it calculate a rotation matrix ?

Comment: Are you familiar with the keyword `this`?  What you show is a non-static _member function_, which means a `QMatrix4x4` will be identified as "`this`".

Comment: It can be used to pass current object as a parameter to a method ? I thought that this matrix is the current matrix of the object. Fo example if I'm working with OpenGL and I'm drawing an object that I want to rotate, this matrix would be the modelview matrix but I'm not pretty sure about it.

Comment: I mean does this function multiply the current matrix (modelview matrix) with a rotation matrix ?

Comment: A non-static member function requires an object instance to be called.  It will rotate the matrix that this function is called on.  `m.rotate(quaternion);` will rotate `m`.

Comment: Building on @DrewDormann's comment, and being very explicit, `m` will be rotated by `quaternion` (unit quaternions can be used as a compact representation of a rotation)

Comment: @user888379 I understand that m will be rotated by quaternion but does this function multiplies the current matrix by the rotation matrix that corresponds to the quaternion ?, I mean does it take the quaternion calculates the rotation matrix then multiplies it by this matrix ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The question is which matrix is "this matrix" ?

"This matrix" refers to the matrix that this member function is called on.

> does it calculate a rotation matrix ?

According to [this source code](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/gui/math3d/qmatrix4x4.cpp.html#_ZN10QMatrix4x46rotateERK11QQuaternion), yes.  The current matrix is multiplied by a rotation matrix that corresponds to the quaternion.